# Why is the set of all non-decreasing sequence not open in the real sequence space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given the set $B=\{a\in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}|\exists C \in \Bbb R \forall n \in \Bbb N:|a(n)<C\}$ with the distance $d(a(n),b(n)):= \sup|a(n)-b(n)|$.

Take the set $J:=\{a\in B| \forall n \in \Bbb N: a(n+1)\geq a(n)\} $

I know that $J$ is not open in the metric space $B$ but I want to make sure I know exactly why.

So take the null sequence $0\in J$. This is an element of J as each member is zero and so the condition $a(n+1)\geq a(n)$ is satisfied as zero is equal to zero.

Next consider an open ball centered at $0$, $B_r(0)$, so the taking the metric $d(0,b(n)):=\sup|0-b(n)|= \sup |b(n)|$ the open ball is $B_r(0)=\{b(n)|d(0,b(n)) <r\}$, In other words $\sup|b(n)|<r$. okay honestly after this I'm stuck. I don't know why no open ball exists in $J$ which is centered at zero . could anyone explain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion is equivalent to the existence of arbitrarily small points in the complement of the set. Now consider the element
$$
c(n) := \begin{cases}
\epsilon & n=1 \\
0 & n \ge 2.
\end{cases}
$$
It violates the condition of $J$, but is close to zero with regard t your metric.

Comment: okay I think I understand...c(n) is arbitrarily close to my null sequence 0 so it exists in an open ball $B_\epsilon(0)$ but it does not exist in Jso then this open ball does not exist soley in J and so J cannot be open ?

Comment: could you tell me if that's correct ?

Comment: Unfortunately my browser does not render comments with math-dollars. Could you rephrase accordingly?

Comment: okay I think I understand...c(n) is arbitrarily close to my null sequence 0 so it exists in an open ball Bϵ(0) but it does not exist in Jso then this open ball does not exist soley in J and so J cannot be open ?I took out the math dollars around the open ball... i thjink this is what you meant

Comment: if not I can rewrite it again, just not sure if that's what you meant or not

Comment: Thanks. The point is that for any open ball about J, if we make epsilon sufficiently small, then c(n) is not in it. An open set (with regard to the topology induced by the metric) has by def. the property that each point contains an open ball about it. And the 0-element violates that condition for J.

Comment: surely though $c_n$ is not in J regardless of how small epsilon is though , no ? considering that it is constructed to have its first entry as some number greater than zero and all the rest zero, which already violates J's condition ? secondly I'm still not totally sure why the 0-element  has NO open ball around it , is it because there are sequences that do belong to J and others that don't that exist within any open ball centred around 0 ?

Comment: "surely though c(n) is not in J regardless of how small epsilon is though , no ?" that's precisely the point.

Comment: I mean even if we didn't make it sufficiently small, like say epsilon was 10000. but perhaps i'm focusing too much on an unimportant detail here

Comment: still though what about my second point about why there is no open ball around the null-element

Comment: Because c(n) is not in it, it's not in J but it's in the open ball. So the open ball is not in J.

Comment: excellent we're on the same page now.. thank you :)